# Modify html from typescript (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I try to modify a part of HTML in a component as we do with JS "innerHTML" in a angular app. I'm a beginner with angular, maybe I missed something important.

Actually look like that (typescript, html (from the same component)):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { GraphService } from '../services/graph.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-content',
  templateUrl: './graph-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph-content.component.scss']
})
export class GraphContentComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() graphName: string;
  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() graphContent: any;
  graphI:string;


  constructor(private graphService:GraphService) { }
  testF(){
    var inputGraph = this.graphService.refreshGraph(this.graphContent);

    //inputGraph should go in DOM and look like : "<div class=\"progress-fill\" style=\"background-color: black;\"><span>XX%</span></div>"
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start list-group-flush">
   <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
     <h5 class="mb-1"> {{ graphName }}</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="horizontal" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="progress-track" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: flex-start;" id="graphInput">
      <!--here comes the content-->
    </div>
    <button (click)="testF()">react</button>
 </div>
```

So `inputGraph` must go in `graphInput` div. Is there a simple way to do it, would it be better to create a component for this part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the property binding for `innerHTML` like  `[innerHTML]`.

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlstring">
```

and in your component.ts file

```
this.htmlstring = `<p> Hello</p>`
```

Comment: I can't add style with this because there is a angular Sanitization process to avoid security problem. How can I do if I want to add something like :`"<div class=\"progress-fill\" style=\"background-color: yellow; width:70%;\"><span>70%</span></div>"`  and keep the style?

Answer (score -1):

¿What kind of data came from **this.graphService.refreshGraph(this.graphContent)**?
¿It´s JSON data?

Maybe you could make a component named `app-input-graph`, with an @Input inputGraph and this html code:

```
<div class="progress-fill" style="background-color: black;">
    <span>{{inputGraph}}</span>
</div>
```

And in app-graph-content:

```
<app-input-graph [inputGraph]="inputGraph"><app-input-graph>
```

Comment: refreshGraph return a string